# L'expression « mise à jour »

Tags: expressions

Est-ce qu'on peut utiliser l'expression  « mise à jour » dans un contexte personnel ?

Un exemple :

Merci d'avoir donné tes nouvelles --- Merci pour la mise à jour

Answer (score 6):

On ne peut pas utiliser « mise à jour » dans ce contexte car cette locution s'applique à un objet, pas à une personne.

Suivant la teneur des nouvelles apportées, on pourrait utiliser les expressions suivantes :

> Merci de m'avoir tenu informé.
>
> Merci de m'avoir mis au courant.
>
> Merci de m'avoir tenu au courant.
>
> Merci du retour.
>
> Merci de m'avoir donné de tes nouvelles